# Blog like QListWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

How to make in Qt item list like QListWidget, but multiple rows, multiple images, buttons like html text link, and text decoration (bold/italic/etc).

[image]

Help me if you know at least one of these options.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is too broad, you're basically asking us to tell you how to design your [custom `QListWidgetItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#subclassing). If you want to learn about how to use a custom `QListWidgetItem` have a go at it and ask when you get stuck. If you want to ask about embedding HTML, images, or text in a `QListWidgetItem` have a go at it and ask when you get stuck. This is not to assist you in programming, not do your programming for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `QListWidget` as you like. Please study this thread:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27777-Customize-QListWidgetItem-how-to

It has all the information you need. The idea is that you need to set custom delegate using the function `setItemDelegate` of your `QListWidget`.

```
class ListDelegate : public QAbstractItemDelegate
{
    public:
        ListDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

        void paint ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const;
        QSize sizeHint ( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const;

        virtual ~ListDelegate();

};
```

In the `paint()` function you may paint all the text/images as you need.